# How to create a table grouping by multiple conditions from multiple variables

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to get the results from an excel dataset with multiple conditions on a group by function. The conditions I want are to have if  my 'days' field is less than 91 days and the employee type not equal to contractor then get a count. I have tried

```
 df[df['days'] < 91].groupby('empType').count()
```

Unfortunately gives me counts of everything since I am grouping on the empType.
I have this:

```
id      empType      days
 1      Contractor   54
 2      Employee     83
 3      Employee     61
 4      Intern       32
```

When I want this:

```
id      empType      days 
 2     Employee      83
 3     Employee      61
 4     Intern        32
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you're missing the second condition from your filter. You can add it with the `&` and enclosing each filter with `()`. Try this:

```
df[(df['days'] < 91) & (df['empType'] != "Contractor")].groupby('empType').count()
```

Comment: Thank you for some reason I didn't think I could do it this way.